# Assertion failure in -[RBSAssertion setInvalidationHandler:]

Tags: ios, ios13

What's this and can I do anything about this:

```
2019-08-09 13:49:36.946141+0300 xxx[2861:1427995] *** Assertion failure in -[RBSAssertion setInvalidationHandler:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/RunningBoardServices/RunningBoard-223.0.2/RunningBoardServices/RBSAssertion.m:189
2019-08-09 13:49:51.091952+0300 xxx[2861:1427995] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'can only call before acquisition'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186ccadf8 0x1869f40a4 0x186bcd7f8 0x1870016d4 0x1897db49c 0x1897dadec 0x1063858ac 0x106386c88 0x10638fe44 0x106399b88 0x1869e8fa8 0x1869ebae4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I vaguely remember seeing this crash last week

Comment: Seems like an iOS 13 beta 6 bug. I have the same issue when opening a new app window.